# Limit with Fourier coefficients

Tags: calculus, limits, fourier-analysis

> Prove that if $f \in C^{k}(\textbf{T})$ and $\{c_n\}$ are the Fourier coefficients of $f$, then $$\lim_{n\to \pm \infty} n^k c_n = 0$$

What I know is that if $f\in C^{k}(\textbf{T})$ then $|c_n| \leq M/|n|^k$ for some constant $M$. Furthermore, computing $$c_n(f^{(k)}) = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_Tf^{(k)}(t)e^{-int}dt = \dfrac{1}{2\pi}[f^{(k-1)}(t)e^{-int}|^{\pi}_{-\pi}+in\int_Tf^{(k-1)}(t)e^{-int} dt ] = ...=(in)^k\int_Tf(t)e^{-int}dt = (in)^kc_n(f)$$ we see that $|c_n n^k| = |c_n(f^{(k)})|$. If I somehow could show $c_n(f^{(k})$ is decreasing with $n$, I guess that would do it? Otherwise, I don't really see how to approach this exercise.

Comment: Apply the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma to $f^{(k)}$

Comment: If the Fourier coefficients are (square) summable, they must converge to zero.

Comment: @Dunham My book states said lemma as "Let $f$ be absolutely integrable in the Riemann sense on a finite or infinite interval $I$. Then $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} \int_I f(u) \sin \lambda u \: du = 0$". Is $|f^{(k)}|$ necessarily Riemann integrable?

Comment: $f^{(k)}$ is continuous by hypothesis.

Comment: @copper.hat And what do we know about $\sum c_n^2$?

Comment: The $|c_k|$ are square summable. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @copper.hat So since $\sum |c_k| < \infty $ we know $c_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Since $f^{(k)}$ has the F.C. $(in)^k c_n$ we conclude $\sum |(in)^k c_n| = \sum |n^kc_n| < \infty $ which implies $n^k c_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Is that correct?

Comment: Since $f^{k}$ is in $L_2(\mathbb{T})$  we know that the Fourier coefficients are square summable, in particular they converge to zero. Hence $n^k c_n \to 0$.